# Is it possible to read a line from a file using StreamTokenizer?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I need to read a line from a file, and output it onto the console.

I have tried using the BufferedReader however this is messing up my StreamTokenizer.lineno(), so I was wondering whether I could tackle this from a different angle.

This is the snippet of my code which is outputting to another file

```
try {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Parsed_Files" + timeStamp + ".csv"));

    boolean eof = false;
    int count = 0;
    do {
        int token = st.nextToken();
        switch (token) {
            case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF:
                System.out.println("End of File encountered.");
                eof = true;
                break;
            default:
                if (token == '\'' || token == '\"') {
                    if (st.sval.length() == 3) {
                        if (isNumeric(st.sval)) {
                            //output to the CSV File
                            System.out.println("Writing to File");
                            out.println("File Name: " + fileName);
                            out.println("Code Number: " + st.sval);
                            out.println("Line: " + br.readLine());
                            out.println("Line Number: " + st.lineno());
                            out.println("-----------------------------------"
                                    + "------------------------------------");

                            out.println("");
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    } while (!eof);
}
```

Comment: can you show us the rest of your code that shows the error please?

Comment: There isn't an error, only the line number being incorrect when the buffered reader is being used

Comment: ok, can you post all that code please?

Comment: I have edited my original question, including the code

Comment: Can we get a sample of what is in the file to run the code please?

Comment: I cannot provide what is in the file, but it is PLSQL code

Comment: Could the problem be that the BufferedReader.readLine is skipping to the next line ?